# Alias assemblies included in the same dll

Tags: c#, .net

I have a NuGet package that contains a series of assemblies that unfortunately all define the same type multiple times. Removing the duplicates is currently not an option as they are a product of generation. This yields a CS0433 compilation error like the following:

```
error CS0433: The type 'AmbiguousType' exists in both 'Assembly1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Assembly2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I tried to address it by adding references to alias each of the assemblies like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="MyPackage" Version="1.0.0"/>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Assembly1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\netstandard2.0\assembly.dll</HintPath>
      <Aliases>Assembly1</Aliases>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Assembly2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\netstandard2.0\assembly.dll</HintPath>
      <Aliases>Assembly2</Aliases>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

then in the C# code I added the following to define the common type:

```cs
extern alias Assembly1;
using AmbiguousType = Assembly1::AssemblyNamespace.AmbiguousType;
```

but now I get a CS0430 that alias `Assembly1` has not been referenced.

Is it possible to resolve this or is this something that just can't be done?

Comment: This comment might give you an idea as to how to assign aliases to nuget references: https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-telemetry-sdk-dotnet/issues/161#issuecomment-721905674